# How to show AlertDialog form the inputMethod

Tags: android, service, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with show AlertDialog when the keyboard in the inputmethod is pressed.
I have try a lot way to do that 
like KeyBoard.java here

`case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                    imeService.showDialog();`

and ImeService who extends InputMethodService here

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("123");
    dialog.setMessage("123");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("123", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "123", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("123", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "123", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    dialog.setNeutralButton("123", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "123", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog a=dialog.create();
    a.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    a.show();
```

and I also have permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

why still wrong?
always shutdown the app

the error log

> 05-02 00:03:40.911 23064-23064/io.github.timeime.time E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
>   05-02 00:03:40.911 23064-23064/io.github.timeime.time E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
>   05-02 00:03:40.911 23064-23064/io.github.timeime.time E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:355)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:324)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:285)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:225)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:578)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:314)
>                                                                                 at io.github.timeime.time.ImeService.showDialog(ImeService.java:60)
>                                                                                 at io.github.timeime.time.KeyboardUtil$1.onKey(KeyboardUtil.java:59)
>                                                                                 at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.detectAndSendKey(KeyboardView.java:831)
>                                                                                 at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1361)
>                                                                                 at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1224)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9993)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2831)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1863)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:982)
>                                                                                 at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:153)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2792)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10228)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5350)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5186)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4626)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4679)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4787)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4653)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4844)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4626)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4679)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4653)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4626)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7312)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7190)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7151)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7422)
>                                                                                 at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                                 at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                               at java.lang.r
>   05-02 00:03:40.911 23064-23064/io.github.timeime.time D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   05-02 00:03:40.911 23064-23064/io.github.timeime.time E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: io.github.timeime.time, PID: 23064
>                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:355)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:324)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:285)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:225)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
>                                                                               at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:578)
>                                                                               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:314)
>                                                                               at io.github.timeime.time.ImeService.showDialog(ImeService.java:60)
>                                                                               at io.github.timeime.time.KeyboardUtil$1.onKey(KeyboardUtil.java:59)
>                                                                               at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.detectAndSendKey(KeyboardView.java:831)
>                                                                               at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1361)
>                                                                               at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1224)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9993)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2514)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2831)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1863)
>                                                                               at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:982)
>                                                                               at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:153)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2792)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10228)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5350)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5186)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4626)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4679)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4787)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4653)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4844)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4626)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4679)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4653)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4626)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7312)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7190)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7151)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7422)
>                                                                               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>                                                                               at android.a

Comment: please post the error log

Comment: Note that `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` requires runtime permissions on API23 and higher

Comment: my API is 25 now

Comment: Then add runtime permissions. Also, The error that us happening is maybe cause by wrong theme in mainfest. See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: how to add runtime permissions

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I can't set the permission